# Calculate the value of sum for any given n

Tags: binomial-coefficients

$2n\choose0$ - $2n\choose2$ + $2n\choose4$ - ... + $(-1)^n$$2n\choose2n$

Q: What's the value for any given n $\in$ $N$?

Task is quite easy for odd n and I completed it. You just have to notice that the first number and the last one are opposite etc. I have a problem with even numbers. I noticed it will be $2^n$, but not always positive. Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help: if you expand $(1+i)^{2n}$, you get that your sum is its real part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The given expression is the real part of $(1+i)^{2n}$. 
\begin{align*}
(1+i)^{2n} &= \left(\sqrt{2}(\cos \pi/4 + i \sin\pi/4)\right)^{2n} \\
&= 2^n (\cos n\pi/2 + i\sin n\pi/2)
\end{align*} 
Thus when $n$ is odd, the sum is zero and when $n = 2k$, sum equals $(-1)^k 2^{2k}$

Comment: How do I know it's the real part of this?

Comment: $i^{2k} = (-1)^k$ and hence real, and $i^{2k+1} = (-1)^k i$ and is imaginary. Hence the given sum can be written as $\binom{2n}{0} + (i)^2 \binom{2n}{2} + i^4 \binom{2n}{4} + \cdots$. Adding the other terms we get $(1+i)^{2n}$. Now we see the required sum is the real part of this expression.

Answer (score -1):

Precalculation + OEIS
http://codepad.org/tjwaQvuT
https://oeis.org/search?q=-4%2C16%2C-64%2C256%2C-1024%2C4096%2C-16384%2C65536%2C-262144%2C1048576%2C

Answer maybe is (-4)^n